# How to disable text which appears when the mouse hoovers over an icon?

Tags: macos, mouse

When I move the mouse to any icon the name of icon automatically appear on the the screen, how can I remove this option?

Comment: I honestly cannot tell what you are asking. Your tags don't seem to be related to the question either. Bear in mind we cannot see over your shoulder; you have to tell us exactly what you're doing & what is happening. If you struggle to explain in English, try to explain clearly in your own language & then run it through [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com)

Comment: Log in to the same account you used to ask the question to be able to reply in comments.